# Atom says "No module named 'pygame'" When I try to run it (mac os)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, atom-editor

I am very new to the Atom editor, I am on mac os and I am using Atom to run python, but when I try to make a game using pygame and then run it, it gives me the "No module named 'pygame".

**Some extra information:**

- Pygame version: "2.0.0.dev6"
- I use 'script' to run python stuff on Atom
- I have already installed pygame on my computer

I have macOS 10.14 Mojave installed and I still have not updated to catilina.

Answer (score 0):

First off, double check you **definitely** have pygame installed, assuming you do, submit a bug report to atom - I don't use atom personally but assuming you are in the python 3 language, I don't think that is a problem with atom.

Comment: I am 100% sure I have pygame because I checked on my IDLE and also on pycharm and they both are working fine